# Why $\overline{\mathbb{Q}_\ell}$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, etale-cohomology

In étale cohomology usually the only well-behaving coefficient sheaves are the finite ones. But one needs a characteristic zero coefficient sheaf for the fixed-point formula to work, thus the $\mathbb{Z}_\ell$. One wants a field coefficient so that the cohomologies are free and the trace can be defined, thus $\mathbb{Q}_\ell$. But in Kiehl-Weissauer usually $\overline{\mathbb{Q}_\ell}$ is used; I've heard that it is for cohomological comparison. Can you elaborate what comparison theorems are present here? Thanks!

Comment: For many results in étale cohomology  $\overline{\Bbb Q}_{\ell}$ is needed. Here is another example: [Étale cohomology of rank one ℓ-adic local systems in positive characteristic](https://arxiv.org/abs/1908.08291), Hard Lefschetz etc.

Comment: Re: the first sentence, you might be interested in reading about the pro-etale topology which fixes this problem: https://arxiv.org/abs/1309.1198